# Finding date/time intervals from multiple rows T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an audit table that stores a master table's "status" values in multiple rows, each row has a date/time stamp. Let's call the master table "Project" and it moves through different status changes: Open, Pending, Closed. However sometimes the Project can move back to Open after it's been closed. Data would be something like this:

```
ProjectId    Date          Status
1234         07-01-2015    Open
1234         07-03-2015    Pending
1234         07-05-2015    Closed
1234         07-06-2015    Open
```

I need to take a date parameter value, and determine what status the Project "1234" was in on that given date.

`ex: Date=07-02-2015 would give me "Open"
Date=07-07-2015 would also give me "Open"
Date=07-03-2015 would give me "Pending"`

The problem I'm having is that the SQL needs to look at the surrounding rows (if any)

Comment: What do you mean by `surrounding rows`?

Comment: What version of sql server?

Comment: 2008 R2, surrounding rows meaning, 07-01 to 07-03 is Open but also 07-06 forward is also Open. I guess a more simplistic explanation is, I need to be able to tell if my Project was status 'x' on date 'x'. This came from a crazy feature request to tell what a Project status was on any given date in the past selected by a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Limit the rows to only rows with date inside the window.
2) Sort the result by date descending (putting the most recent at the top)
3) Select the first row

```
DECLARE @CheckDate DATETIME = '07-07-2015',
        @ProjectId INT = 1234

-- To ignore time, set the check date to the first millisecond of the 
-- next day and use a less than operator
SET @CheckDate = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @CheckDate) + 1, 0)

SELECT TOP 1 
         [Status]
FROM     [Project]
WHERE    [ProjectId] = @ProjectId
AND      [Date] < @CheckDate
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

Comment: That was my approach too. But I want to add (just as a hint), that this construction should be aware of the time of status change. Most of the time this comes up as a change request later and will create huge re-work!

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2012 or later, you can do this with `Lead` as follows:

```
declare @date datetime = '7-2-15' --or whatever

select ProjectID, Status from ( 
    select *
        , lead(date) over (partition by projectID order by date) as NextEvent 
    from MyTable) a
where @date between [date] and isnull(NextEvent, @date + 1)
```

Otherwise, you can approximate `lead` using `row_number` and a self-join.

Note, depending on how precise your dates are, you may want to use something like `where @date >= date and @date < isnull(NextEvent, @date + 1)` instead of `between`.